# Can't reset form after submission using React-Hook-Form and Radix-UI

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js, react-hook-form, radix-ui

I'm trying to build a simple budget app and the first step is to have a form to submit trnsactions made. I have simplified the form to using only a radio group component for demonstration as I'm having the same issue with most components and this will be easier to explain using one as a demonstration. I have read the docs for both RHF and RadixUI on how to properly implement the type of form I want, however, after submitting I want to reset it and there is an issue with resetting fields within a controller. The code is below:

```
"use client";

// state
import { useEffect } from "react";

// components
import * as RadioGroup from "@radix-ui/react-radio-group";

// utils
import { useForm, SubmitHandler, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { z } from "zod";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";

const BudgetForm = () => {
  // schema
  const schema = z.object({
    transactionType: z.enum(["income", "expense"]),
  });

  // types
  type FormValues = z.infer<typeof schema>;

  // form
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { isSubmitSuccessful },
  } = useForm<FormValues>({
    resolver: zodResolver(schema),
    defaultValues: {
      transactionType: "expense",
    },
  });

  // handlers
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormValues> = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  // effects
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSubmitSuccessful) {
      reset({
        transactionType: "expense",
      });
    }
  }, [reset, isSubmitSuccessful]);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-4">
      {/* transaction type */}
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="transactionType">Type of transaction</label>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="transactionType"
          render={({ field }) => {
            console.log(field.value);

            return (
              <RadioGroup.Root
                defaultValue={field.value}
                onValueChange={field.onChange}
                aria-label="Select a transaction type"
                className="flex items-center gap-4"
              >
                <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
                  <RadioGroup.Item
                    id="income"
                    value="income"
                    className="h-4 w-4 rounded-full bg-white flex items-center justify-center"
                  >
                    <RadioGroup.Indicator className="bg-red-500 h-2 w-2 rounded-full" />
                  </RadioGroup.Item>
                  <label htmlFor="income">Income</label>
                </div>
                <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
                  <RadioGroup.Item
                    id="expense"
                    value="expense"
                    className="h-4 w-4 rounded-full bg-white flex items-center justify-center"
                  >
                    <RadioGroup.Indicator className="bg-red-500 h-2 w-2 rounded-full" />
                  </RadioGroup.Item>
                  <label htmlFor="expense">Expense</label>
                </div>
              </RadioGroup.Root>
            );
          }}
        />
      </div>
      {/* submit */}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default BudgetForm;
```

What should happen is after submit, the effect runs and clears the form, however if you console.log field.value it renders the submitted value and then the default value so on reset it sets it to the previous submitted value rather than the required default value. Trying to fix this I've followed instructions on setting default values in the reset such as:

```
reset({
 transactionType:'expense' 
})
```

I can't seem to find a resolution to this issue.

as explained above I have tried what the docs suggested.